# An exercise in the book:" Curves and surfaces" written by Montiel and Ros

Tags: differential-geometry

In that book, page 17, Exercise 1.34, the authors write:
"
Let $\alpha:I\to\mathbb R^3$ be a curve p.b.a.l. with positive curvature
defined on an interval $I\subset \mathbb R$ symmetric relative to the origin. We define
another curve $\beta:I\to \mathbb R^3$ by $\beta(s)=\alpha(-s)$, for each $s\in I$. Show that $\beta$ is a
curve p.b.a.l. and that $k_\beta(s)=k_\alpha(-s)$ and $\tau_\beta(s)=-\tau_\alpha(-s)$ for each $s\in I$. "
There is no problem in the first two questions, but when I compute (many times) the torsion of $\beta$, I get $\tau_\beta(s)=\tau_\alpha(-s)$. Did I wrong or there is a misprint in this exercise?
I will be appreciated if someone can help.

Comment: You're right. $\tau$ involves $\alpha', \alpha'',$ and $\alpha'''$, and flipping the time direction only makes the derivatives of odd order negative, which cancel each other out.

Comment: Thanks jackal! It really make me confused for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think a bit more geometrically and consider the Frenet formulas, you see that $\mathbf T$ changes direction, $\mathbf N$ does not, and so $\mathbf B$ also changes direction. Then the equation $$\frac{d\mathbf B}{ds} = -\tau\mathbf N$$ will tell us that the torsion of your curve $\beta$ does not change sign (we pick up a negative on $\mathbf B$ and a negative from $s\mapsto -s$, but $\mathbf N$ hasn't changed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Ted.

Comment: @ZERO, welcome to the site. When you're satisfied with the answer (and, if you're not, ask follow-up questions), please accept it so that the question goes off the unanswered list. Also, the differential geometry text linked in my profile may be of interest.

Comment: @TedShifrin I recently saw a test attempt for this exercise in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604880/the-problem-in-my-proof-that-if-betas-alpha-s-then-the-torsions-of-the-c, there it got $ B ′_{\beta} (s) = (- T_{\alpha} (- s)) \times (−N ′_{\alpha} (- s)) + T ′ _ {\alpha} (- s) \times N_{\alpha} (- s) $.

Comment: But I don't understand why $ T ′ _{\alpha} (- s) \times N_{\alpha } (- s) = 0 $ to conclude $ B ′_{\beta} (s) = (- T _ {\alpha} (- s)) \times (−N ′ {\alpha} (- s)) $ . I know that the vectors must be parallel for this to happen, but I don't understand that part. Could you give me a help please?

Comment: @Curious That's the first Frenet equation.